# Spacy: save parsed model

Tags: python, serialization, nlp, pickle, spacy

I am using Spacy, which is a Python Natural Language Processing library, to parse raw text into this more complex Object Oriented format, more specifically a dependency tree.

The above operation takes a while to execute: I need to load a very expensive model, and then parse a very large quantity of text. I would prefer to save some time in subsequent executions, as to iterate faster on handling the data after done this initial parsing.

How can I "save" these results after the first run, and then reload these preprocessed versions faster in subsequent runs?

**PICKLE:** When trying to use pickle I get the following error unserializing the Docs/Tokens classes:

```
File "spacy/tokens/token.pyx", line 56, in spacy.tokens.token.Token.__cinit__ (spacy/tokens/token.cpp:3868)
TypeError: __cinit__() takes exactly 3 positional arguments (0 given)
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you get this resolved? can you give an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of what you are doing? I'm interested ;)

Comment: Thanks for commenting... I did actually resolved this by doing roughly the following: reimplementing 2 classes from Spacy, the Span (for sentences) and Token classes. Once the raw text is parsed, I then transform the Spacy Doc object in a list of Spans. I then pickle that list to disk. The interesting part is that I also implemented the iterators, thus it was "transparent", as I didn't had to change the rest of my code that handles those objects.

Comment: Might write a proper answer following the mcve principle at some point soon.

Comment: yes i would like to see it, if you do i'll up vote it for sure

Answer (score 0):

No pickle solution, but I wrote [this script](https://github.com/cltl/SpaCy-to-NAF) in the past to store SpaCy output as XML (in the NAF format).

Depending on your pipeline, you could also try storing the output in CoNLL format (e.g. [CoNLL-U](http://universaldependencies.org/format.html)). This makes your code interoperable with many other NLP tools, which is great because you could just change parsers with no issue.

I don't have example code for this, but the process should be similar.